# How do I load page javascript after async loading of my manifest file

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, asynchronous

I am trying to convert my app to asynchronous javascript loading with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", async: true %>
```

The problem is that any page-specific scripts are being run before Jquery is loaded asynchronously. How can I defer those until the application.js manifest file has been loaded.

I tried wrapping my page js in `$(window).load(function(){});` but this did not help. I still see the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

**Update**:

This seems to be working for me, but I'd like someone to confirm that it is the correct approach:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", async: true, onload: 'pageScripts()' %>
```

Then the page script like:

```
<script>
  function pageScripts() {
    // do something
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not simply write your javascript inside a `window.onload` scope ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your approach is correct however I would suggest to limit your Async only for production since in development Sprockets hasn't concatinated all of the files yet.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application", async: Rails.env.production?, onload: 'pageScripts()' %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll give you the check since you bothered responding. BTW, You can test this in development by putting this in development.rb `config.assets.debug = false` .. this forces the manifest file in dev mode, but generally it's a better idea to do `async: Rails.env.production?` as you suggested. Thanks.

Comment: what is difference between :async => true and async: Rails.env.production? ?

Comment: @KickButtowski the difference is that when `:async => true` it will always Async, but when `async: Rails.env.production?` it will async only when it is in production